# A question about space quotient and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological space and let be $\sim_X$ and $\sim_Y$ the corresponding equivalence relations on $X$ and $Y$. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ an homeomorphism, suppose we are in the following hypotheses

> $$x\sim_Xy\iff f(x)\sim_Y f(y)$$

---

> **Question** Can we conclude that $$X/\sim_X\;\simeq\;Y/\sim_Y$$
>   If yes, can the hypotheses be weakened?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for example, see [When are quotients of homeomorphic spaces homeomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3041546/when-are-quotients-of-homeomorphic-spaces-homeomorphic)

Comment: Thanks! Duplicate!